# How to Load Multiple React Components Dynamically?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Hi I'd like to load multiple react components from a directory dynamically. Such that somebody only has to add a component in a directory for it to be loaded. I'm thinking something along the lines like:

```
import * as dynamicComponents from './dynamicComponents';

const toAdd = [] dynamicComponents.forEach(function(component){  
toAdd.push( Route path={component.link} component={component.implmentation} /> })


render(<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Template}>
        <IndexRoute component={Main} />
        {toAdd}
      </Route>
    </Router>   
   </Provider>,  
  document.getElementById('root') );
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your first import statement won't work in Babel. Try this package:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-wildcard
```

Add it to your .babelrc with:

```
{
    "plugins": ["wildcard"]
}
```

You may not be using Babel in your environment, but essentially you need to solve the the problem of loading from a wildcard or dynamic path. That is probably the hard part.

You'll also need to be sure that every file dropped into the directory exports a React component class as its default export and has a static function returning a link.

```
const SomeReactComponent = () => (<p>Rendering something.</p>);

//Export link as static member of the class.
SomeReactComponent.link = '/some/react/component/routing/link';

export default SomeReactComponent;
```

Then code like the following will work at compile-time:

```
import * as dynamicComponents from './dynamicComponents';

const toAdd = dynamicComponents.map( (ComponentClass) => <Route path={ComponentClass.link} component={ComponentClass} /> );
```

This is a compile-time solution. If you want a run-time solution, investigate using importers other than ES6 import, which I believe cannot be used dynamically at run-time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed to get started. I just tried an implementation based on your guidance, and I'm getting the properties I was looking for!